# Filename tab completion within bash backtick environment

Tags: bash, ubuntu-10.04, tab-completion, backticks

I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 and I've ran into a little bit of a snag with bash completions within backticks. Here's an example to illustrate:

I save streaming URL:s to my radio-stations in text files, and I usually start listening by typing

```
$ mplayer `cat ~/stations/some.fm`
```

It would be great if I could use tab completion at:

```
$ mplayer `cat ~/stations/<tab>
```

In this case, however, the tab completion doesn't seem to match files, only directories. So I get

```
$ mplayer `cat ~/stations/<tab>
subdir1       subdir2
$ mplayer `cat ~/stations/
```

But no files! A workaround is to use

```
$ cat ~/stations/some.fm | xargs mplayer
```

In this case tab completion works, but I would prefer to use the backtick version. Not for this example alone, but this bit me in many other situations as well.

Does anyone here know how to fix this / where the filter is defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
$ mplayer $(cat ~/stations/<tab>
```

instead; it does the same thing.

Comment: Great! This works. Curious why backticks don't though. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe because backticks are *old-style* now, but I sill prefer them.

Comment: @you both: Yes, the reason is because the backticks are *old-school* and $() is the new backtick. But, as an old fart, I also prefer backticks.

Comment: Backticks aren't necessarily _old-school_ (even `sh` supports `$()`); the problem is that it's hard to know when it's a opening or closing one. Nesting is a hell.